# How do I check whether an int variable is divisible by a certain number?

Tags: python

I've been creating a two-player random number generator based guessing game and I made it so that the players can choose how many points they need to win. I can't seem to remember how to check whether an int variable is divisible by a certain number, as I am trying to use this to determine if the points total is a valid number.
This is the section of code I'm looking at right now:

```
  if winpoint/5 != 0:
    blah = "Win points must be a multiple of 5. Try again.\n"
    for l in blah:
      sys.stdout.write(l)
      sys.stdout.flush()
      t.sleep(0.015)
    t.sleep(0.5)
    pointsdec()
```

**pointsdec is the name of the function this is in by the way**

I meant for this section of code to happen only when *winpoint* is a multiple of 5, i.e: 30, but this piece of code triggers regardless of what the user types. Can someone help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%` instead of `/`. `winpoint / 5` will only be zero if `winpoint` (or its absolute value) is less than 5. `winpoint % 5` is only zero if (the absolute value of) `pinpoint` is divisible by 5 (otherwise, there would be a non-zero remainder).